# Undeclared 'GET_FUNCTIONAL_CACHE_SIZE' when creating Oracle Text index

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-text

Having 11.2.0.3 Standard one installed, I try to create a text index.

```
CREATE INDEX MyTextIndex ON <Table>(<Field>)
     INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
```

Index creation fails with the below error.

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-29874: warning in the execution of ODCIINDEXALTER
>   routine
>
> ORA-29960: line 1, DRG-50857: oracle error in get functional cache
>   size
>
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 27: PLS-00302: component
>   'GET_FUNCTIONAL_CACHE_SIZE' must be declared

Why do I see this error and how can I actually set *functional_cache_size*?

Comment: Just re-run it and it'll work just fine. Temporary cache seems to fill up somehow. Weird error though.